# Term reference redirect after node save

Tags: redirection, taxonomy-terms

i am new to Drupal. I have few nodes with term reference. After creating nodes with term reference, i want to redirect user not on created node, but on term page. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is. But it is not a part of any module I know. Could you link module name in your question to it's project on drupal.org please?

Comment: What is the term page?

Comment: Taxonomy has vocabulary, and each vocabulary has its own terms. What i meant is, If you display that particular term on a full view.

Comment: Using rules module you can redirect to other pages after the node has been saved. Try that module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set redirect state for your node form. For example

```
function my_module_form_alter( &$form, &$form_state, $form_id ){
  if($form_id == 'your_node_form_id') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = '_mymodule_node_redirect'; 
  }
}

/**
 * Custom Submit Handler to set conditional redirection rule.
 */
function _mymodule_node_redirect($form, &$form_state) {
  // If terms are already in the system.
  if($form_state['values]['your_taxonomy_field']['und'][0]['tid'] ==  'tid_to_compare_with') {
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'whereever you want';
 }
}
```